# How to pass docker-compose files to 'docker stack deploy' dynamically?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can run the following to launch multiple compose files:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose.test.yml
```

I'm using this inside a `gitlab-ci` pipeline:

```
deploy:
  script:
    - ssh user@$server "docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose.test.yml appname"
```

Problem: I'd like to pass the docker-compose files dynamically to a gitlab-ci script:

```
ssh user@$server "docker stack deploy $ARRAY_OF_DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILES appname"
```

Question: is that possible somehow for swarm mode?

Comment: IMHO it is not gitlab nor swarm related. its just about shell variable expansion in ssh ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to create an intermediate docker-compose file as follows:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml config > docker-compose.stack.yml
```

And then deploy it with:
`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.stack.yml`

Not the solution that I was looking for, but at least it works.